# How to get the Users Date of Joining of Facebook?

Tags: python, facebook

I want to get the date and time on which the user joined Facebook (not the facebook application). I am using python for this. Can you suggest me what is the way to get that value, I can't seem to find it. Also what permissions would be required to get this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Survey says: no

https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+join+date&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100721153233AApV1zG

http://www.ceveni.com/2010/09/when-did-i-join-facebook.html

But, what you could do is keep using the pagination links property of the `/me/feed` until you get no more results and then you'd have ballpark figure.

Comment: But that would fail in case of Timeline, and someone writes a back post, would it?

Comment: That's why it is a ballpark figure.  :)